# "Clear" window to make room for new user controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm usually working with Windows Forms Applications, but I'm currently needing Windows Presentation Foundation for design purposes.

What I am needing to do is clear out the current open window and fill it with new user controls as though a new window has been opened. In short, open a new window without actually opening a new window, similar to navigating to a new page in a web browser. (Still the same window open in the Taskbar, no extras.)

I was unsure if there was a specific class or control that made this easy to do. If someone could enlighten me on the way to do this in WPF, I would be very pleased.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possible ways - here are a few that come to mind:

**Navigation**

In WPF, you can actually navigate to different xaml pages.  In this scenario, you would define a number of pages that a main page could navigate to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx

**Programmatic**

You can do it the old school way and just clear out all of the controls in a window.  For example (in the context of a window):

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

stackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl1());
stackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl2());

this.Content = stackPanel;
```